# Return to zero CountdownEvent

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, countdownevent

I'm trying to use a **[CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235708.aspx)** to only allow threads to continue when the event's count is zero, however I would like the initial count to be zero.  In effect I'd like a *return to zero* behaviour whereby the event is signalled whenever the count is zero and threads are made to wait whenever it's greater than zero.

I can initialize a Countdown event with 0 initial count but when I try to add to the count I get *InvalidOperationException* "CountdownEvent_Increment_AlreadyZero" .

Is there an alternative class or another way that I can use Countdown event in order to avoid this limitation?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  How did you do it?

Answer (score 7):

## Edit

```
public void Dispatch()
{
    using (var ev = new CountdownEvent(1))
    {
        foreach (var task in <collection_of_tasks_to_start>)
        {
            ev.AddCount();
            // start *task* here. Don't forget to pass *ev* to it!
        }

        ev.Signal();
        ev.Wait();
    }
}

// task code
void Handler(CountdownEvent ev)
{
    try
    {
        // do task logic
    }
    finally
    {
        ev.Signal();
    }
}
```

**Why and how this works?**

1. If you haven't spawned any tasks

   - nothing will happen and `Dispatch` will just finish normally.
   - `ev.Signal` makes sure that once `ev.Wait` is called, initial value of the counter is `0` and `Wait` will not block execution
2. If you spawned at least one task

   - we have two cases to consider: fast- and slow-running tasks and understand how they affect execution at point where `ev.Wait()` is called.

     - fast tasks, *i.e. tasks that will complete before we reach the end.*

       - at the `ev.Wait()` the situation is equivalent to point 1.
     - slow tasks, *i.e. tasks that haven't completed before we reach the end.*

       - at the `ev.Wait()` the counter is not equal to `0` anymore, because of all the `ev.AddCount()` executed. Thus, execution will hold.
       - once all running tasks complete (and have corresponding `ev.Signal()` lines executed) the counter drops to `0` and execution resumes exiting the routine

## Original answer

You wrote:

> I am performing an operation that will create an unknown number of child operations (not tasks or threads)

So what are they? You should do something like this:

```
CountdownEvent ev;  
public void foo() {
    ev = new CountdownEvent(1);
    foreach ( <task in tasks_to_start> ) {
         ev.AddCount();
         // enter code here which starts your task
    }
    ev.Signal();
    ev.Wait();
}

public static void youtTask(CountdownEvent ev) {
    // some work
    // ...
    // after all is done
    ev.Signal();
}
```

Comment: So you are using an additional countdown of 1 to indicate tasks are still being added?

Answer (score 3):

If you can use .NET 4.0 or [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) for .NET 3.5 (which has a backport of the .NET 4 TPL features), you might check out the [Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx) class.  It allows you to coordinate multiple parallel tasks so that they do not continue until all participants in the barrier have signaled their arrival.  It should also meet your requirement to have participants appear and disappear during the course of processing.

Answer (score 2):

So in essence you need an "on/off switch", not a synchronization object that can be set up with an arbitrary countdown. `CountdownEvent` is not appropriate for such cases.

Why don't you just use a [`Semaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) with an initial count of one?

Comment: not quite, it is important that i have this counting behaviour.  In effect I am performing an operation that will create an unknown number of child operations (not tasks or threads), when each operation starts i receive a signal and when each operation ends I receive a signal.  I don't want to continue until all of the child operations completes.  (fyi, I'm writing quite a tricky bind around a native dll, hence the unusual requirement)

Comment: Do the (unknown in number) operations get created all at once, or is there a possibility that they may be created "in batches"? In other words, can you say "OK, I created X of them, and I know I will not create any more until those X all complete" at some point?

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384749.aspx

**Edit**
Sorry that was vague.  Using SOReader's answer where you have a countdown event in each parent starting at 1 - then using TryAddCount in children increment and later decrement parents back to 1, then in the parent decrement from 1 to zero when children are done, and finally decrement the count in the parent of the parent thread.  So a tree-like series of countdownevents.

I'm not experienced with multithreading but at first glance that's what I would try.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems like is a common tree walk forking technique. Each time you would have recursed, you instead kick off another concurrent operation (enqueue it to a thread pool, etc). But you need to wait for all the subbranches to finish at the end. Simply add 1 to the countdown event for each sub-operation you kick off, and signal it at the end of each sub-operation. It is safe to do as long as you arrange the algorithm so it won't signal until it adds for each child operation.

I should add that you *don't* need to know the count up front, just make it 1 at the root, and each time you fork off to a child, add 1, then signal at the end of each one, and it will dynamically handle any tree with no up-front cost.

CountdownEvent has a method Add which lets you increase the count in flight.

Does that make sense? I may be way off track of what you are trying to accomplish.

However, if you really want a CountdownEvent that behaves the way you specified, it is quite easy to wrap a couple of interlocked operations in a class to do what you say.

However, CountdownEvent is built to be feather-weight, it's almost free if nobody waits before it's signalled. In the expensive case, it is optimal, no matter how many tasks (etc) it will only have to make one kernel transition to signal and one to wait, worst case.

To implement what you propose would require a synchronization around the signalling and resetting of the event. The countdown event relies on one simple principle, only the transition from nonzero to zero in a Signal call can possibly signal the event. There is no race, since it is not possible for more than one thread to change the value at one time (it's interlocked) so it is only possible for one thread to try to signal the event object (that awakens the other waiting thread). Perfect.

However, if you have multiple threads setting and resetting it, you need to sync around the set and reset, since the count might jitter a couple of times and multiple threads would all simultaneously be trying to set or reset the event. (Setting, resetting, and waiting for an event are all expensive because they all have to make a kernel transition and cause context switches). It wouldn't work unless you synchronized around something to protect the set/reset transitions. If they added this to CountdownEvent it would no longer be nearly optimal, it would be significantly more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

How about semaphores: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

Edit: The following post discusses why what you describe is not recommended and also suggests a workaround: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelextensions/thread/aa49f92c-01a8-4901-9846-91bc1587f3ae

Comment: could you give an example of how they could be used?  I thought about them but couldn't get away from needing to know the maximum count.

Comment: can you post your non-working code so I can better understand what you are trying to accompolish?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Queue object to add "work" into and take out again.

Only when the Queue is empty you move on.

But yeah, we're gonna need specifics here...

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615413/register-new-thread-to-already-defined-barrier), but in the context of `Barrier`.

Actually If you think about it, `CountdownEvent` is a one phase `Barrier`.

So in order to avoide the limitation of:

> I can initialize a Countdown event with 0 initial count but when I try
>   to add to the count I get InvalidOperationException
>   "CountdownEvent_Increment_AlreadyZero".

you may just move on to `Barrier` and use its `AddParticipant` or `RemoveParticipan` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// call on ctor:
void InitializeCountdown()
{
    counter = new CountdownEvent(1);
}

// whenever you want to wait for completion of all tasks:
void WaitForCountdown(Action doSomething = null)
{
    counter.Signal();
    counter.Wait();

    // optionally do something here
    doSomething?.Invoke();

    counter.Reset(); // to be able to reuse the counter
}
```

Basically you initialize the `CountdownEvent` with `1`, so that it's in a non-signaled state, and with each `AddCount()` call you are increasing the counter, and with each Signal call you are decreasing it, always staying above 1.

In your wait thread you first signal it once to decrease the initial 1 value to 0, and if there are no threads running, `Wail()` will immediately stop blocking, but if there are other threads that are still running, the wait thread will wait until they signal.

But, once the counter hits 0, all subsequent AddCount calls will throw an exception, you need to Reset the counter first.

**Note:** If another task starts in parallel during `WaitForCountdown()` (before `counter.Reset()`), it's `AddCount()` call will fail. You may want to use a `lock` to overcome.